# $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are points on a circle such that $AB=BC=CD=10 cm$, $DA=20 cm$. What is the radius of the circle?

Tags: geometry

$A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are four consecutive points on a circle such that the chords $AB=BC=CD=10.0$ cm and $DA=20.0$ cm. What is the radius of the circle (in cm)?

(1) $10.0$

(2) $10\sqrt{2}$

(3) $10\sqrt{3}$

(4) $20.0$

Let $O$ be the centre of the circle. Let $M$ and $N$ be the mid-points of $BC$ and $DA$, respectively. Clearly, $OM \perp BC$ and $ON \perp DA$. Also, $OA$ and $OB$ are radii. Considering the right angled triangles $\triangle OMB$ and $\triangle ONA$, we get
\begin{align}
OA^2 &=OM^2+MB^2=OM^2+5^2=OM^2+25,\\
OB^2 &=ON^2+NA^2=ON^2+10^2=ON^2+100,
\end{align}
respectively. Thus, $OM^2+25=ON^2+100 \Rightarrow OM^2-ON^2=75$. How to proceed from this point?

Comment: FYI, using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24AB%3DBC%3DCD%3D10%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24DA%3D20%24&p=1), I found the now closed & deleted post [Find the circumradius of a particular cyclic quadrilateral given the lengths of its chords](/q/3479143/602049) from Dec. $17$, $2019$. The question text is "If $4$ consecutive chords of lengths $10\text{ cm}$, $10\text{ cm}$, $10\text{ cm}$ and $20\text{ cm}$ in a cyclic quadrilateral are given, how can one find the radius of the circle?". Also, note its $2$ answers both conclude that $r = 10$ cm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ a = b = c = 10, d = 20 $$

$$ s = {a + b + c + d \over 2} = {50 \over 2} = 25 $$

We know that the radius of the circle is given by
$$
r = \sqrt{ (a b + c d) (a c + b d) (a d + b c) \over
          (s - a) (s - b) (s - c) (s - d) } =
\sqrt{ (100 + 200) (100 + 200) (200 + 100) \over
 (25 - 10) (25 - 10) (25 - 10) (25 - 20)}
$$

Simplifying, we get
$$
r = \sqrt{ 300 \times 300 \times 300 \over 15 \times 15 \times 15 \times 5}
= {1 \over 4} \sqrt{1600} = {1 \over 4} 40 = 10
$$

Thus, the radius $r$ of the circle is
$$
r = 10 \ \mbox{cm}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Drawing a sketch of the quadrilateral, one realizes it is a isosceles trapezoid.

Let $\theta = \angle ABC $, then

$10 \cos \theta = -5 $

$ \theta = \cos^{-1}(-\frac{1}{2}) = \dfrac{2 \pi}{3} = 120^\circ $

Hence, by extending the perpendicular bisector of segments $AB$ and $BC$, one concludes that (using symmetry)

$ r \sin( \dfrac{\pi}{2} - \dfrac{\pi}{3} ) = 5 $

From which

$ r = 10 $

Answer (score 0):

Since the trapezoid base ratio is 2, the sides are 30-60-90 triangles. Mirroring the trapezoid across the base, you therefore form a 120-degree angle and have a regular hexagon, which must be circumscribed since the first half of it (the given trapezoid) is. Its maximal diameter is therefore the circle diameter, but it is also the trapezoid base. So the circle radius must be 10.0 cm.